# How to convert strings to numbers

Tags: c

In a program I am working on, I want to allow the user to enter symbolic names which the program will convert to predefined numbers.

For example, if the user types `AA` then program would use value `10`, but if the user types `BB` then the program would use the value `20`.

How can I convert the strings to numbers?

Comment: Please make your question clear, it's completely unclear.

Comment: by a lot of manual coding, comparing input to strings, one by one

Comment: It looks like you are very confused about what is happenning in your computer for a compiled C program.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to use a lookup table. Use `scanf` to read a string and then call the lookup function to convert the string to a value.

```
int value = -1;
char string[32];
if ( scanf( "%31s", string ) == 1 )
    value = valueForString( string );
```

Here's a simple lookup table

```
typedef struct
{
    const char *string;
    int value;
}
    stLookup;

static stLookup lookup[] =
{
    {  "AA", 10  },
    {  "BB", 20  },
    {  NULL, -1  }
};
```

And here's the `valueForString` function

```
int valueForString( const char *string )
{
    stLookup *lptr;

    for ( lptr = lookup; lptr->string != NULL; lptr++ )
        if ( strcmp( lptr->string, string ) == 0 )
            break;

    return( lptr->value );
}
```

Comment: Minor: Why 32/30 and not `string[32]; if ( scanf( "%31s", ...`?

Comment: @chux You are correct. I tend to make buffers much larger than necessary, and not use the whole buffer, because I prefer to waste a few (temporary) bytes (on the stack) rather than risk an off-by-one error. I changed the answer to avoid any confusion :)

Answer (score 2):

you can create an array containing the names and an array containing the corresponding values, like

```
char *a[10] = {"AA", "BB", ...};
int   b[10] = {10, 20, ...};
```

then you do a scanf to a char * pointer for example named input, then you can iterate the array a to find the index and then retrieve the corresponding index in array b:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    if (!strcmp(input, a[i]))
        break;
}

if (i != 10)
    value = b[i];
```

then you get the value by input the name 'AA'.

noting: it's not the real code that can run, but I think it may look simpler than pseudo code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to *interpret* some expression (e.g. `AA+BB` being *evaluated* to 30, since -or in an environment where-  `AA` is bound to 10 and `BB` is bound to 20), using the variables of your C program (or some other variables or [bindings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_binding)).

I'm not sure it is in general possible and sensible (what is the behavior you expect if the user types `abort()` ?).

Maybe you could embed some existing interpreter, e.g. [Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) or [Lua](http://www.lua.org/), in your program. Otherwise, consider [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser) some expressions (you'll need to formalize their syntax e.g. in [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) and define their [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_%28computer_science%29))  into some [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) (AST) then code an interpreter for the evaluation of such ASTs in some environment.

Notice that at runtime, for a compiled C program, the C variable `AA` (declared in your C source code as `int AA;`) does not exist anymore (it is known at compile time only, not at runtime)

If you are on Linux, perhaps read about [dlsym(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) (which might give you the ability to find the address of some global variable or symbol at runtime, given its name).

BTW, read about [call stacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) & [continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) & [interpreted languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language) & [eval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval)

Comment: the variable still exists, and is known. its name otoh, is not

Comment: No, I claim that at runtime C variables do not exist. Only *locations* exist.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` is the c funtion you should use